# rxjava combineLatest in Kotlin style

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I am new in kotlin coroutines. Like in RXJAVA we have combineLatest operator for updating old response. First data will be fetched from local database(update the UI) and new data will come from server after hitting the network request(update the UI with new data). How can I get the same functionality using Kotlin without using callback hell.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [`buildSequence {}`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/build-sequence.html) and utilize the `yield` behavior. You just have to consider that the operation providing the values might be blocking. Thus you'd have to wrap it with some `async` as well.